# Rails 3.1.3 - Loading assets from subfolder in vendor/assets/stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I want to load an external stylesheet from app/vendor/assets/stylesheets/twitter... but Sprockets keeps complaining that the file can't be found.  My app/assets/stylesheets/application.css looks like this:

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap
*= require sass_main
*/
```

I tried adding the subdirectory to the asset path like this:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/vendor/assets/stylesheets/twitter"
```

...but no luck. What I gotta do?

Comment: Could you please clarify if you need the whole directory or just a file in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap
*= require sass_main
*= require_directory ./twitter
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If `require_directory ./twitter` did the trick then I believe the problem was in typo in your asset path:

Are you sure you were having `/vendor` dir under `app/`? Usually this sits in `Rails.root` so you were correct at the beginning by adding it to `config.assets.paths` but you should have left out the `/app` in between like this:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/stylesheets/twitter"
```